# Удаление одинаковых элементов в многомерном массиве PHP

Tags: php

Есть многомерный массив:

```
[0] => array

           [a] => a10
           [b] => a20
           [c] => ccc30
           [d] => a40
           [e] => a50
           ...
[1] => array 

           [a] => b10
           [b] => b20
           [c] => b30
           [d] => b40
           [e] => b50
           ...
[2] => array 

           [a] => c10
           [b] => c20
           [c] => ccc30
           [d] => c40
           [e] => c50
           ...
[3]
.....
```

Нужно сделать, чтобы на выходе получился такой массив:

```
[0] => array

           [a] => a10
           [b] => a20
           [c] => ccc30
           [d] => a40+c40
           [e] => a50
           ...
[1] => array 

           [a] => b10
           [b] => b20
           [c] => b30
           [d] => b40
           [e] => b50
           ...

[3]
.....
```

Удалили из исходного массива все элементы (массивы), совпавшие по ключу `[c]`, кроме первого попавшегося. 
Суммировали все значения с ключом `[d]` удаляемых элементов (массивов) + оригинального (не удаленного).

Comment: Может посмотреть в сторону array_unique() ?

Comment: array_unique() вернет мне массив без повторяющихся элементов, а как же мне тогда собрать сумму значений в ключе [d] ?  Да и как использовать эту ф-цию для многомерного массива?..

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! здесь задают вопросы и дают ответы. сформулируйте, пожалуйста, о чём именно вы хотите спросить, и изложите это в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit] сразу под текстом вопроса.

Comment: Сам решил. В лоб и грубо. Если есть более изящное решение, велкам. Написал в ответах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может у кого-то есть решение поизящнее..

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($исх_массив); $i++){
    $arr1[$i] = $исх_массив[$i]['с'];
    $arr2[$i] = $исх_массив[$i]['d'];
}

$temp_arr = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++){
    if (!array_key_exists($arr1[$i], $temp_arr)){
        for ($j=$i+1; $j<count($arr1); $j++){
            if ($arr1[$i] == $arr1[$j]){
                $arr2[$i] = $arr2[$i] + $arr2[$j]
            }
        }
        if (!array_key_exists($arr1[$i], $temp_arr)){
            $temp_arr[$arr1[$i]] = $arr2[$i];
        }else{
            $temp_arr[$arr1[$i]] .= $arr2[$i];
        }
    }
}

//var_dump($temp_arr);
```

На выходе получим массив, где оригинальным индексам из исходного массива (`$исх_массив['c']`) соответствуют суммы из индексов `$исх_массив['d']` 
Это конечно часть того, о чем я писал в начале, но саму суть оно решает.